# how to connect between tow combo boxes

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I have a dict like this:

```
data_dict = {'2' : [1,1], '3':[1,2], 4:[2,2], 5:[2,3]}
```

and I have 2 combo boxes, the first one has the `data_dict.keys()` and the second one has a text build from each key's list, for example `'1+1'`. now I want to connect between the combo boxes so if I choose `4` in the first combo box, the second one changes to `'2+2'`, and if I choose `'1+1'` in the second combo box, the first one changes to `2`. is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it so that whenever you click on the first combobox, a  function  updates the text of the other.

Use something like the following, as seen in the [docs](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QComboBox.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QComboBox.setItemText)

```
PySide.QtGui.QComboBox.setItemText(index, data_dict[key])
```

where the key is the value of the first combobox.

Comment: and what about the opposite way ? if I make the same thing, everytime I change and item, the app enters to infinite loop.

Comment: @user2234234 Do you mean if you change the text of the combobox, it'll change the first combobox? In that case, write a second function to do the opposite, rather than create one that has to get used for both. One will only get fired when you change the first, and one will only get fired when you change the second.

Comment: Ok, but this functions are fired when you change one manually, the the function will changed the other one, and it will fire it`s function, that changes the first one and so on.. inifinite loop.

Comment: No, the difference is that you're thinking the function will fire whenever the combobox changes, but I'm suggesting that the function will fire whenever the user clicks or activates the combobox. It's a subtle difference.